# how to use multipal components in angular2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am new in `angular2`, I am trying to use two components in single page but it gives me `404 error`.

this is my two `.ts` files

app.ts

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {events} from './event.component';

@Component(
    {
        selector: 'contact'
    })
    @View({

        templateUrl: './Travel Operator/login.html',

        directives: [events]
})

export class Contact {
}

bootstrap(Contact);
```

and event.component.ts

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from "angular2/angular2";

@Component(
    {

        selector: 'events'
    })
@View({
        template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
})


export class events {

    }
}

bootstrap(events);
```

and i am trying to use it on my main index.html file like

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>First Angular App</h1>

    <div id="content">
        <contact></contact>
    </div>
    <div id="events">
        <events></events>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

but it gives

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:55777/event.component"
>   error

I am stuck over there please help

Comment: This is more likely a backend problem, not angular.

Comment: it tries to load http://localhost:55777/event.component rather than **http://localhost:55777/event.component.js**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the module containing your event component isn't correctly loaded. It's rather a problem with your SystemJS configuration. Perhaps you don't put the TypeScript files with an `app` or `src` folder.

From the 5 Min Quickstart (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart):

```
var map = {
  'app': 'app', // 'dist',
  (...)
}

var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  (...)
};
```

In this case, both JS files for components (resulting from TypeScript transpilation) are located in the same folder (the `app` one) so `import {events} from './event.component';` will look for an `event.component.js` file in the `app` folder.

Comment: can we create angular2 project in asp.net mvc4?